# MYSQL - How can I loop trough an oboject and post meta fields to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an object as follows,

```
$object = (object) ['meta_age' => '17', 'meta_name' => 'jack', 'meta_lastname' => 'ripper', 'recording' => 'binarystring'];
```

Made from my $_POST. With MYSQL how would I get all the fields that start with meta and post those to the database? Keep in mind the meta can change every time, so I would need some sort of loop. The user has control over what the meta is. So it could also be

```
$object = (object) ['meta_rank' => '4', 'meta_score' => '55', 'recording' => 'binarystring'];
```

I would like to post this in the meta table. That has the following columns

```
id | type | content
```

So for the last one it would be

```
1 | rank | 4
2 | score | 55
```

I would probably use PHP to get all the fields that start with meta_ and put them in a separate (object)[] and then want to loop trough that object with MYSQL.

Comment: yeap you guessed it right, you'll need a loop, just to point out, where is the id in relation to the user and their input meta, shouldn't that be related to them

Comment: Well, 1) Loop throught your obj, 2) Check if you have key with "meta", 3) If yes, split the key to get the second part (age, name,...) then do some Insert with meta key name + value

Comment: Yes you are right, but to simplify I left out that ID sorry if it is confusing

Comment: @MickaëlLeger but do I need to loop the insert with PHP? Or is there a MYSQL way to take an array and post all the values?

Comment: You can do an array and make one big Insert yes ! http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```php
$object = (object) ['meta_age' => '17', 'meta_name' => 'jack', 'meta_lastname' => 'ripper', 'recording' => 'binarystring'];

$prepareInsert = [];
foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'meta') > -1) {
        $splitKey = explode('_', $key);
        $metaKey = $splitKey[1];

        $prepareInsert[$metaKey] = $value;
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
array(3) {
  ["age"]=>
  string(2) "17"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "jack"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(6) "ripper"
}
```

Now just loop throught your array and do your insert !

```php
$sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO table_name (type, content) VALUES ';
foreach ($prepareInsert as $metaKey => $value) {
    $sqlQuery .= '("'.$metaKey.'","'.$value.'"),';
}
$sqlQuery = substr($sqlQuery, 0, -1); // Just to remove the last ','
```

Output is :

`"INSERT INTO table_name (type, content) VALUES ("age","17"),("name","jack"),("lastname","ripper")"`

And now you can insert all at once